# cv2 Getting a list of pixels values from a picture

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, rgb

`enter code here`Hello,

I am using python 2.7, cv2 and I need to get all the pixel values from a image. First of all i resized the image to be with the resolution of (62,74).The way I am doing it is :

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img  = cv2.imread("photo1.jpg")
resized = cv2.resize(img,(62,74), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)

pix = resized[62,74]
print pix
```

But  everytime I run the code it returns this:

```
pix = resized[62,74]
IndexError: index 62 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 62
```

I don't know what's wrong with it ...

Thanks

Comment: resized[61,73] is the last legit one. remember, that you have to index from 0 to n-1 in python/c/java

Comment: @berak Well a changed the value and the return was:               IndexError: index 73 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 62

Comment: ah, sorry, row/col confusion, too. (62,74) in resize means: width=62, height=74, but resized[62,74] means: resized at y=62 and x=74

Comment: @berak thanks, I changed the positions  of the numbers into resized[y,x] and it worked. Thank you!

Comment: i'll promise, that will bite you more than once ;)

Comment: @berak or anyone, just one more question. I need to get several  pixels values of the image I decided to put it in a single list and I will transform the values of the list into a CSV file. But when I append the pixel value into a list and print it, it returns this odd thing: [array([78, 76, 70], dtype=uint8)]. I just need the numbers, what should I do?

Comment: each rbg pixel is a numpy arr on it's own. if you don't want that, `print resized[73,61,0], resized[73,61,1], resized[73,61,2]`